# Swift 3 - Custom cells not showing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After a few hours of trying to figure out why my customs cells aren't showing, I have hit a bit of a bump. Using the MVC pattern:

### Model.swift

```
struct studentProperties {
   var _title : String!
   var _forename : String!
   var _surname : String!
}

class MainModel {

   // Singleton instances
   static let modelInstance = MainModel()
   static var structInstance = studentProperties()

   // Array of structs
   var studentArray: [studentProperties] = []

   // MARK: - Initialization
   private init() {}

   func studentInput(title: String, forename: String, surname: String) {
       MainModel.structInstance._title = title
       MainModel.structInstance._forename = forename
       MainModel.structInstance._surname = surname
    }
}
```

### CreateStudentController.swift

I won't show the whole file, but this code is inside of a save button - user inputs data, and that data gets append to the array in model

```
 @IBAction private func saveNewStudentButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // Put student data into the struct properties in model
    MainModel.modelInstance.studentInput(title: studentTitle.text!, forename: studentForename.text!, surname: studentSurname.text!)

    // Append the user input
    MainModel.modelInstance.studentArray.append(MainModel.structInstance)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "returnToStudentsList", sender: sender)
 }
```

### MainStudentController.swift

```
class MainStudentController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   //MARK: - @IBOutlets
   @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

   //MARK: - @IBActions
   @IBAction func addStudentButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

       performSegue(withIdentifier: "createStudentSegue", sender: sender)
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       myTableView.delegate = self
       myTableView.dataSource = self

       myTableView.reloadData()
   }

   // MARK: - Table view data source
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

       return 1
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       print(MainModel.modelInstance.studentArray.count)
       return MainModel.modelInstance.studentArray.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell: MainCell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell

       cell.studentTitle?.text = MainModel.modelInstance.studentArray[0]._title
       cell.studentForename?.text = MainModel.modelInstance.studentArray[0]._forename
       cell.studentSurname?.text = MainModel.modelInstance.studentArray[0]._surname

       return cell
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       myTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
   }
}
```

There is another file - which is of UITableViewCell, but it literally only has the outlets for my custom cell.

### Issue

The issue I am currently experiencing is (I think) around this method?:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print(MainModel.modelInstance.studentArray.count)
    return MainModel.modelInstance.studentArray.count
}
```

User inputs data -> it gets append to that array -> thus now I am using those elements from the array to represent the amount of rows there will be.

Sadly, it currently isn't showing any rows? I could add multiple elements and it still wouldn't show any rows. Yet, when I print that same line out, it shows that there are elements inside(dependant on how many times I add new data). I'm a little confused as to why this isn't adding rows?

I'm not sure if it's something I am missing or isn't correct in code. I would appreciate if anyone could see where I have gone wrong?

Hopefully that explains my situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this code, your problem is just that the table view itself is not getting reloaded. Your only reload call is in `viewDidLoad`, so it only gets loaded when your view loads the first time (that method only gets called once). You can fix this easily by moving `myTableView.reloadData()` from `viewDidLoad` into `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. That should be all you need to do.

Something like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
       super.viewWillAppear()
       myTableView.reloadData()
   }
```

Comment: Ah, I thought because I was dismissing the old view, then going back to it after the user had put new data in the viewDidLoad would still work. That has cleared up a lot, thank you.

Comment: One other thing worth noting is that the new code will work as long as your table only updates when you are looking at another view controller. If at some point you make updates to your data without leaving the screen, you will need to trigger `reloadData` manually as well since `viewWillAppear` will not get called.

Comment: Alright, I will be more than sure to keep that in mind, cheers again Dima!